# How do I clean out old log files from Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I 'fetch last 100 rows' it gives me dozens of old log files like

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.2018-03-16.log
-------------------------------------
```

Going all the way back to March! Yet I have log retention to 7 days.

[image]

It makes it hard to track down problem because I have to search through the file for the log I want and scroll instead of just seeing the relevant logs or searching for 'exception' or 'error'. I have load balancer set up and I have from 2-5 instances.